# Can't resolve error ([-93] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:)

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to use the [SQLite4Java](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/) library in my java application, when I try to open the database I get the following error:

> [-93] cannot load library:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   sqlite4java-win32-x86 in
>   java.library.path

I've tried to ensure that the library is referenced correctly:

***Library manager***

[image: Library Manager]

***Project Explorer***

[image: Project Explorer]

***Import Statements***

[image: Import Statements]

I don't use additional libraries in Java often at all and this is the first time I have come across this, am I missing an additional setting that needs to be made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the answer is fairly simple, when copying the .jar to my directory it seems the additional .DLL files weren't copied with it.

> ◦Native libraries (*.dll, *.so,
>   *.jnilib) - place them in the same directory with sqlite4java.jar;

One copy and paste command later, success!